# Secured communication in a real time game

Tags: security, ssl, tcp, udp

I want to create a real time multiplayer game and I wonder how should I secure and identify each user. For instance imagine I have a map with 5 players in it, each player sends every 1/60 seconds his position via udp to the server. How should the message look like? Maybe the udp message from the client to the server could be:

> repos player *player id* to *x*, *y*

But someone then could send billions of messages to my server with any player ID he wants and basically manage every user's position. Any ideas how that should be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rightly notice that spoofing is the main threat here.

One way to address it is to require players to sign in first. On successful sign in, give them a token or a temporary key and then use this key to check the validity of each message.

For checking validity, you can either sign the messages with one of digital signature schemes or simply include the secret temporary token along with the message.

You can further improve this scheme by replacing this secret key every few minutes. This will need a separate message type, which has to be also authenticated with an existing temporary key.